# where to code business logic in nodejs with expressjs, mongoosejs and redis

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, express, redis, mongoose

My business logic includes mongodb operations and redis operations on one request. I do not know where we should put logic code to. In Java project, we have **DAO**, **service** and **controler** objects. but in nodejs projects, I don't know where to put my code. shall I put logic code to `routes/index.js`?

```
app.post('/deal', function(req, res) {
    ... //TODO: here

});
```

or create a kind of **service objects** such as what we do in Java proejct?

Comment: I dont use router for logic like that. Instead I create "managers" which in turn takes a db object(for database implementation of choice).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a question that might help: [Mongoose-based app architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454441/mongoose-based-app-architecture/15572522#comment24204434_15572522)

You should also look at the http://mean.io stack, as their templates will show you how to *best* structure your app, including where to store your logic.

Comment: OK, I will check it out soon, then response you

Comment: Henry, have you settled on a structure yet ? Care to share some thoughts? Java/IOC is my background and struggling to organize an express project with legacy DB and complex business logic: rest resource representations are definitely not one to one with db entities (complex DTO) and plenty of rules engines decisions ....just do not know best practice or examples  to organize

Comment: @Sbham , have you settled on a structure yet?