# Can i divide index.html file into different files in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

Hi i have now a big project done in angularjs and my index.html file starts to be very long :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">

<head>
<title>InTouch</title>

<base href="/">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Utilise LESS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/ngprogress-lite.min.css">

</head>

<body ng-app="InTouch">
<!--<div ng-include="" src="'./partials/header.html'"></div>-->
<div ng-view>
</div>
</div>

<!-- <div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div ng-include="" src="'./partials/footer.html'"></div>
  </div>
</div> -->

<!-- Fix for old browsers -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/less.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularLib/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularLib/angular-animate.js">
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="bootstrap@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularLib/angular-messages.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" type="text/javascript" src="angularLib/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularLib/angular-strap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularLib/angular-strap.tpl.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularLib/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularLib/angular-css.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="angularLib/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularLib/http-auth-interceptor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularLib/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularLib/angular-file-upload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularLib/ngprogress-lite.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="angularLib/ngStorage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularLib/angular-growl-notifications.js"></script>
<script src="angularLib/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="angularConstant/geolocation_msgs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularConstant/useragentmsgs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularConstant/config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularControllers/NavbarAngCtrl.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularControllers/AdminNavbarAngCtrl.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularControllers/MainHeaderAngCtrl.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="angularControllers/modal/ModalInstanceAngCtrl.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="angularControllers/MainAngCtrl.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularControllers/AnnouncesAngCtrl.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularControllers/profile/ProfileAngCtrl.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularControllers/profile/ActualityAngCtrl.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularControllers/modal/AboutModalAngCtrl.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularControllers/profile/HistoricAngCtrl.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularControllers/profile/MessageAngCtrl.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularControllers/profile/PictureAngCtrl.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularControllers/profile/ReputationAngCtrl.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularControllers/profile/WalletAngCtrl.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularControllers/admin/AdminAngCtrl.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularDirectives/compareToValidatorDrct.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularDirectives/fmRatingDrct.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularDirectives/onBlurDrct.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularDirectives/onFocusDrct.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularDirectives/emailAvailableValidatorDrct.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularDirectives/userFilterDrct.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularDirectives/fmCheckboxListDrct.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularDirectives/usernameAvailableValidatorDrct.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="angularDirectives/paginationDrct.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularDirectives/fileUploadDrct.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularDirectives/headerDrct.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularDirectives/adminHeaderDrct.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularFactories/GeolocalisationFctr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularFactories/UserAgentFctr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularFactories/AuthFctr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularFactories/SessionFctr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularFactories/UserFctr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularFactories/AnnouncesFctr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularFactories/AnnouncesFromUserFctr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularFactories/CommentsFctr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularFactories/FriendsFctr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularFactories/MessagesFctr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularFactories/RoomsFctr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularFactories/SocketFctr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularFactories/ProfileFctr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularFilters/starsFltr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularFilters/cutFltr.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

What is the method to divide this file into different ones ? Is it a problem to have such a long file ? Would'nt it have any problem of loading ?

Comment: Now the real question is, do you have a basic arithmetic jQuery plugin?

Comment: Never mind, it was a joke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@felix, this is not a problem to have a long index file as you have presented. Consider the tag for instance ng-include, you may want to uncomment and use this as a resource.

```
<!--<div ng-include="" src="'./partials/header.html'"></div>-->
```

This will fetch html asynchronously after initial load.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Now consider your `app.js`, it will register as many modules that your project is using. These modules will be loaded asynchronously. So it is not such a terrible thing having as many script tags listed as you do.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

When you build this for production, I would recommend minifying and concatenating your scripts however, that will reduce the number of requests to the server.

The AngularJS Yeoman project has examples on how to do that.
https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular

Comment: It can be a problem as the project grows though. For example my Chromium tabs straight up freeze if I'm trying to open my app if it's not minified. It's an annoying issue and I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

For development, what you have is fine. However when you deploy to production, you will want to combine all of the JavaScript files into one so that you have a single script. This SO question: [Combine and Minify Multiple CSS / JS Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287823/combine-and-minify-multiple-css-js-files) gives some good suggestions on how to do this. The most upvoted tool is [minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/).

Here are some reasons why combining the files would be a good idea:

1. It's faster. One single download is more efficient than many small downloads. (See this question: [Is it better to load many small JavaScript files or one large JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043275/is-it-better-to-load-many-small-javascript-files-or-one-large-javascript-file))
2. SEO. Many search engine spiders only index up to a certain number of bytes. You will want to make your `head` as succinct as possible in order to allow the engine to get to the real content.

Comment: Warning: It can get too big, and your Chrome tabs will freeze when you try to develop locally.