# Any way to control Javascript Async Load Order?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, deferred-loading

How do I set the load and execution order of two external `async` Javascript files?

Given the following...

```
<script src="framework.js" async></script> // Larger file
<script src="scripts.js" async></script> // Small file
```

Though second in order `scripts.js` is downloading and executing before `framework.js` due to it's file size, but `scripts.js` is dependent on `framework.js`.

Is there a way natively to specify the load and execution order whilst still maintaining `async` properties?

Comment: Much better to use something like requirejs to manage your dependencies...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893046/how-to-manage-client-side-javascript-dependencies

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You want to use `defer` if you want to preserve the execution order. What `defer` does is it async downloads the script, but defers execution till html parsing is done.

```
<script src="framework.js" defer></script>
<script src="scripts.js" defer></script>
```

However, you may want to start creating custom bundles once the number of scripts go higher.

You can see the difference [here](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you need a solution for IE9 (since it does not support the `defer` attribute), I have created a small loader script:

https://github.com/mudroljub/js-async-loader

It loads all your scripts asynchronously and then executes them in order.

Comment: With all due respect, IE9 does not support the `let` keyword either. Plus, it would be neat if it loaded scripts as soon as they were both available and it was their turn. Instead of having to wait for all scripts to download before executing any.

Comment: You are totally correct and thanks for mention it. I have reverted the code to ES5, which was the original syntax. But it still waits for all the scripts, though.

Comment: Haha yea, I suppose simplicity was sort of the strength of this snippet so I get it.