# angular is not defined after adding async attribute in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, seo, audit

I am trying to increase the performance of my web page in chrome Audit.I added 'async' to my script tag  as follows,

```
<body ng-cloak id="body">
   <script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,places&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBMxfoPEGblWmG-R6eLz6Oe0FS6wPEnMNA"
    async></script><!-- bower:js -->
   <script src="vendor/app.deps.js" async></script><!-- endinject -->
   <script>angular.module('templates', []);</script><!-- inject:js -->
   <script src="js/app-1591858972321.js" async></script>
   <script src="js/partials.min.js" async></script><!-- endinject -->

</body>
```

I am getting the following error when it is loaded,

```
angular is not defined in 'js/app-1591858972321.js'
angular is not defined in 'js/partials.min.js'
```

Can anyone please suggest me to resolve these error.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The angular scripts have to load in a defined order. The vendors needs to ne loaded before your Script. Async destroys the order. Try its with defer instand of async [Any way to control Javascript Async Load Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28893519/any-way-to-control-javascript-async-load-order)