# Structure of a node js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm new to `node js` so please forgive me if I say something wrong. I want to create a project and test it locally.
So I've created a `node js` project with (in same directory):

1. `app.js` --> where I create the `localhost:8080`
2. `index.html` --> my `html` main page

   - within this, I've a call to `test.js` script

Those are my files:

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

port = 8080;
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Server in ' + port);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="test.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

// Non important stuff
```

But when I try to import `npm` libraries to `test.js` script, as shown right above, I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "express".
 Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

And if I try to use `require`, it shows me this error:

```
// test.js:1 ==> const axios = require('axios')

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at test.js:1
(anonymous) @ test.js:1
```

**EDIT CHANGED MY DIRECTORY**
My folder is this:

[image: project]

I've changed my directory but still remains the same problem

Previous question: Why is showing me that error? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you install the Axios package?

Comment: @MikeMapanare yes i did with ´npm i axios´

Comment: Could you add your package.json file

Comment: Oi hol'up... you're importing your npm packages into your browser?  You're not supposed to do that!

Comment: suggestion: don't serve pages out of the same folder your server is in. Your node modules and `app.js` are "server side" and `index.html` should be "client side". At the moment the html page has access to node modules (and `app.js`) directly which might lead to a lot of confusion about what goes where. Create a subfolder called 'public' (say) and get express.static to only serve pubic pages.

Comment: if you want to test the node js app use Postman to test it. If you want to call the api from frontend you can use [httprequests](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp) in javascript

Comment: @traktor sorry for bothering you, but how can i use `axios` library in `test.js` if I can import in it?

Comment: The simplest is to follow the answer from @Mythos - include `axios.min.js` from a CDN in `index.html` and place script tags to include `test.js` (which imports axios) after it. Theoretically you could extend the _server_ code to support serving axios from `serverPath/node_modules/axios/dist/axios.min.js` but I'm not sure it's the greatest idea and suggest proceeding  further along your learning curve without it at this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` is not a built-in javascript function. It is provided by node.js which is **server-side** runtime environment for javascript. You are not supposed to load npm packages directly into a browser.

If you want to use `axios` package in a browser environment, you can load it from CDN (or download it and host it locally with a `script` tag).

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: how could I use a library in the client side then? only with this format?

Comment: I told you how to use `axios`. It is available as npm package and for browser both. If you want to use a library that's only available as npm package, you can try something like [Browserify](https://browserify.org/). See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35071937/use-npm-package-on-client-side)