# Use a javascript file as a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I need a solution for managing js files in my project.

Is there any way that i can reference a js file like this in my html?

```
<script>
   var someName = use("somejsfile.js")
</script>
```

And to use it like this

```
<input onclick="someName.saveThisInput()">
```

Currently the js file in my project is made like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {});

var abc = "some global var";
// a lot of other globals

function saveThisInput(){}
function saveThisInput1(){}
function saveThisInput2(){}
```

**EDIT**

I can't make any changes to the preexisting js files so require.js won't work.
My goal is to merge two or more such js files having name conflicts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage client-side JavaScript dependencies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893046/how-to-manage-client-side-javascript-dependencies)

Comment: What's the ultimate purpose? In what environment/context are you trying to load individual files? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The js files i am supposed to work with are a mess. They are giant ugly beasts that i have to work with. I want namespaces so that my current module will use the namespace object instead of the global variables coming from those files.

Comment: @AnshuSrivastava fix those "ugly beasts" files so they do everything in their own closure and explicitly set things needed to be externally referencable `;(function () { /* do stuff */ ; if(!window.fileNameSpace) window.fileNameSpace = someGeneratedObject;}());`

Comment: I simply don't have that kind of time and that would confuse other people.

Comment: if you want to load a script after then try [jQuery.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/), otherways I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you can use namespace in js edit the js file to look like:

```
var hello = {

  world: function() {
      alert("hello world!");
  },

  foo: function() {
      alert("foo");
  }
};
```

and use it like:

```
hello.world();
```